# AWK command does not join two outputs normally

Tags: awk, sed

I have a simple task to join output from the `lsblk` command with output from the `df` command on the field which contains the mount point.

Example output from `df`:

```
$ df -P --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed /^Filesystem/d
/dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV    51339744   8118908   40583220      17% /
/dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV       515006720 214044372  274731772      44% /dockerssd
/dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV      1547129060  83285716 1385183760       6% /dockerhdd
/dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV    515006720  76061148  412714996      16% /var/lib/docker
```

Output of `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | egrep -v "fd0|ram|loop|sr0|hdc|cdrom|[SWAP]"


sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 /
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd
```

I am using Awk; here is my current code:

```
awk '{ print $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " arr[$4] }
/^\// { arr[$6]=$1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 }' <<< $(
    df -P --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} |
    sed -e /^Filesystem/d
    lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT |
    egrep -v "fd0|ram|loop|sr0|hdc|cdrom|[SWAP]")
```

Here's the output I currently get:

```
/dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8118908 40583220
/dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214044380 274731764
/dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83285716 1385183760
/dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76061152 412714992
sda 53687091200
sda1 53684994048
dm-3 53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 51339744 8118908 40583220 17%
sdb 2147483648000
sdb1 2147482599424
dm-1 536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 515006720 76061152 412714992 16%
dm-2 1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 1547129060 83285716 1385183760 6%
sdc 536870912000
sdc1 536869863424
dm-0 536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 515006720 214044380 274731764 44%
```

I don't need to have this part of the output:

```
/dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8118908 40583220
/dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214044380 274731764
/dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83285716 1385183760
/dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76061152 412714992
```

For me, it is enough to have:

```
sda 53687091200
sda1 53684994048
dm-3 53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 51339744 8118908 40583220 17%
sdb 2147483648000
sdb1 2147482599424
dm-1 536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 515006720 76061152 412714992 16%
dm-2 1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 1547129060 83285716 1385183760 6%
sdc 536870912000
sdc1 536869863424
dm-0 536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 515006720 214044380 274731764 44%
```

Could You help me please, how to divide this output? Maybe some fix in my Awk command?

Comment: As an aside, the regex `[SWAP]` matches anything which contains an uppercase S, W, A, or P character.

Comment: `this <<<$(that)` is just a really weird way to write `that | this` with some curious corner cases which you probably don't want to have to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is rather weird. Probably refactor along the lines of

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {
    if ($1 ~ /^\//) arr[$6]=$1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 
    next }
/fd0|ram|loop|sr0|hdc|cdrom|\[SWAP\]/ { next }
{ print $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " arr[$4] }' \
    <(df -P --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay}) \
    <(lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT)
```

`Filesystem` doesn't match `^/` so I took that out.  The regex `[SWAP]` was incorrect; I assume you meant to match that literally. Awk can do everything `egrep` and `sed` can do, so I refactored those out.

The beef here is the `next` inside the first condition, to avoid printing those lines. The refactoring to read two separate file handles also makes the script somewhat more idiomatic and, hopefully, understandable.